# What is the best way to go about reopening a question for a second time?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

Long story short, a post was marked as a duplicate.  I nominated it for being reopened, and it was reopened.  Then, it was again marked as a duplicate (again wrongfully so).  Since I can no longer vote to reopen the question, what can I do?

**EDIT (specifics):**
Here's the newer [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898236/java-how-many-string-objects) that I answered, which was marked as a *duplicate* twice.  I just don't understand.  Here's the supposed [original form of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180866/how-many-string-objects-will-be-created-in-memory).

What I don't understand is the latter is a complete subset of the question that I answered, which additionally included methods like: `substring()`, `toString()` and `toLowerCase()`.

So in spite of quite obviously encapsulating more material than the *original question*, and having much more attention, it was closed twice.

Again, I can no longer vote to reopen, since I got it reopened once.  I flagged it instead, but can no longer flag it again.  Since I'm not a mod, I can't really do anything anymore.

As was stated in one of the comments in this thread, perhaps the new was is indeed a duplicate, but nonetheless, it seems that the newer one should remain open in light of receiving more attention and have (IMO) higher quality answers.

**EDIT 2:**
Apparently the "original" question also got marked as a duplicate.  There is a long chain of duplicates that eventually point to [Questions about Java's String pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool), which I shouldn't be closed, but again, I'm still not certain the the *newer* question should be closed, either.

Comment: Well, I don't think it deserves reopening.  Normally I'm a stickler for duplicates being actual duplicates, but this one rises quite a bit above my threshold for duplicate detection.  Couple that with the fact that it's not a great question anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention. Explain the situation in detail. Include any relevant links. If the evidence is on your side, a mod can re-open it.

Also, if you post the link and evidence in your meta question here, people from meta can take a look and possibly get enough votes to re-open it.

Comment: unfortunately I also already flagged it, so I can't do that again.  I'm pretty sure that I'm correct about it not being a duplicate, and I'm not on a witch hunt.  I just want to get the question reopened...

Comment: It seems like this may no longer be a possibility, which is pretty unfortunate.

Comment: @SteveP., looking at the question just now, I'm actually part of the camp that thinks it *is* a duplicate. It's an edge case, but I'd argue that while the  exact mechanics of the questions are different, the logic and the underlying explanation is the same in both. Your question has superior answers though, so I think your question should be re-opened and the other question marked as a duplicate of yours, even though yours is newer.

Comment: Fair enough.  Someone else also suggested to close the older one and keep the newer one, too.  Again, I'm okay with that, but nonethless, it seems like there is no longer anything that I can do, since I reopened it once and already flagged it.  Once I get above 10,000 rep, will I be able to reopen it, or do I have to be a mod?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the 10k tools that would be able to help. Only communal decisions or diamond moderators can affect it.

Comment: I made an edit to the post.  Hopefully people will agree and vote to reopen it.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would take a moment to consider whether the question *really* should be reopened. I mean, it was closed *twice*, and presumably not for no reason at all. If you are still convinced that it should indeed be reopened and is in fact a valid question, not a duplicate etc., then flagging for moderator attention is the best option, as the other answer also describes.

Comment: I asked in detail in one of my other [questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191113/meaning-of-duplicate-discrepancy), but no one responded.  Basically the *duplicate* was a subset of the question that I answered, but no one seemed to care.  Not sure if it was group thinking or not reading or maybe I'm just wrong...

Comment: @BenLee, I'm taking the fifth; but perhaps.

Comment: @SteveP. Any chance you can show us which question you're talking about (the one that this post concerns)?

Comment: The meta post is linked in my original comment to you ("questions").  In the meta posts are links to the "original" question and the one that I answered that was marked as a duplicate.  In the meta post is also an explanation of why I think it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I made an edit to this post based off of your response and Ben's.  Hopefully it will attract enough attention to warrant a reopening of the question.